# Как исключить из выборки конкретную таблицу SQL?

Tags: sql

Допустим, есть запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.id, posts.title, posts.text, posts.author, posts.date FROM posts 
INNER JOIN relate
WHERE relate.posts_id = posts.id
```

Как получить такой же результат, но не перечислять все поля из таблицы posts?

Comment: тебе ещё в прошлом вопросе написали, а ты взял и удалил вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1312714/191482...видимо всё понял... ан .нет... ничего не понял

Comment: Я удалил, чтобы очистить разум, так сказать, я чё то в своем же вопросе затерялся и решил заново задать его. Кроме того, ответ-то не дали. А если до сих ПОР не понятно, то задам максимально просто, точнее правлю вопрос.

Comment: тебе в комментах писали `SELECT posts.* FROM......`

Comment: Аааа, .* это входило в запрос? Хах, смешно, просто он после этого смайлик пустил, я думал, что это часть смайлика, прошу прощения.